# How to understand the grammar for "won betting on the match"

Tags: sentence-structure

> They passed a group of goblins who were cackling over a sack of gold that they had undoubtedly **won betting on the match**, and who seemed quite unperturbed by the trouble at the campsite.

I'm confused about the grammar for "*won betting on the match*" in this sentence. Is there an omission in this case? I figure it might be something like this: ...*they had undoubtedly won when they were betting on the match.* ? If this understanding is incorrect, how should we understand it then?

Comment: [Nonfinite verbs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonfinite_verb) are atemporal, that is, they can be placed anywhere in time as they are not inflected by grammatical tense. For example: *Coming downstairs, she saw (had seen) the man running away*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly idiomatic.

> She fell walking on the ice
>
> He sprained his ankle playing football.

or

> The boat sank crossing the Atlantic.

What I think you may be finding odd is that you're understanding **won** as an *outcome* not an event that occurs while another is in progress.  This would be semantically strange:

> She passed taking the exam.

But this is not as strange:

> Taking the exam, she passed.

With such an outcome, this construction would be least odd, at least to my ear:

> Having taken the exam, she passed.

But we can understand the participle clause as referring to an action that was *instrumental* to the outcome:

> They robbed the museum, entering via an air vent.

Just as *walking on the ice* led to her fall, *betting on the match* led to their win.

Perhaps once again a comma might have come to your aid:

> ... they won, betting on the match.

This could be understood as a kind of absolute construction. It is semantically related to the main clause but syntactically disjunct.

Comment: Maybe, It's clearer to put: ...won by/through betting on the match?

Comment: That is what I meant by understanding the clause as "instrumental".  But we don't need to  use  **by** there.  *He won some money  betting on the horses.*

Comment: well, is it wrong to add that 'by'?

Comment: When the meaning of the participle clause is clearly *instrumental*, we can add **by**.  I think it would be a little odd to say *The boat sank by crossing the Atlantic.*

Comment: How about: The boat sank while crossing the Atlantic. and They won through betting on the match.? Are these two sentences correct or idiomatic?

Comment: **through** is sometimes used to express an instrumental relationship. It's no better than **by** however.  Yes, often the participial clause expresses an ongoing action during which the action of the main clause occurs, so **while** could be used in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "won betting on the match" does need to be fixed, and your proposed correction would do so, but your proposal is not ideal because other minor problems also plague the sentence.

Your second use of the pronoun "they" in this sentence is a problem. Who had won the sack of gold? The goblins, or the "They" who had appeared at the start of the sentence? I'd restrict "they" to referring to only one specific group. To refer to the goblins again, you could use another general word, such as in

> …gold that *the creatures* had undoubtedly…

Your use of "betting" is also confusing. You seem to be using the word as a gerund (a noun, and the means by which the goblins won the gold), but it looks like a verb (in the present progressive tense).

You're either trying to say

> the goblins won the gold by means of a bet that they had placed, on the match

or you're trying to say

> the moment at which the goblins won the gold was the moment at which they were placing a bet, on the match

The first of those two is probably the idea you're trying to convey. (Plus, any bet placed on the match would not have paid off until the match was complete, which would have been after the bet had been placed, so these things would not have both happened at the same moment.)

I'd correct the original sentence by transforming it into the following proposal, because it addresses the two points I've noted.

> They passed a group of goblins who were cackling over a sack of gold undoubtedly won by a bet placed on the match, and who seemed quite unperturbed by the trouble at the campsite.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it and it doesn't need to be fixed.